# How to configure GeoIP on a shared server?

Tags: php, geoip

I want to configure **[GeoIP](http://php.net/manual/en/book.geoip.php)** to redirect domain to a subdomains according to country IP address in a shared server. I have created a custom `php.ini` to import *geoip.so* then in my `index.php` I added this code:

```
<?php
    require_once('/home/fuiba/php.ini');
    $gi = geoip_open('GeoIP.dat', GEOIP_MEMORY_CACHE);
    $country = geoip_country_code_by_addr($gi, $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);

    geoip_close($gi);
    $my_countries = 'fr';
    if (strtolower($country) == $my_countries) {
        header('Location: fr.fuiba.org');
    }
    $my_countriessss = 'us';
    if (strtolower($country) == $my_countriessss) {
        header('Location: en.fuiba.org');
    }
?>
```

In the browser I get this error:

```
extension=geoip.so
Fatal error: Call to undefined function geoip_open() in /home/fuiba/public_html/index.php on line 3
```

The GeoIP is installed in the Server. I checked it on info.php: **geoip version 1.0.8**.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't include a php.ini with a php script, and you don't need to since `phpinfo()` return that it's already installed.

What you need to do in order to make GeoLite work is to first include `geoip.inc` file `include("include/geoip.inc");`

Here is where you can find it if you don't already have it :
https://github.com/maxmind/geoip-api-php/blob/master/src/geoip.inc

```
<?php
   include("include/geoip.inc");
   $country = geoip_country_code_by_addr($gi, $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);

    geoip_close($gi);
    $my_countries = 'fr';
    if (strtolower($country) == $my_countries) {
        header('Location: fr.fuiba.org');
    }
    $my_countriessss = 'us';
    if (strtolower($country) == $my_countriessss) {
        header('Location: en.fuiba.org');
    }
?>
```

Comment: Thanks Isaac. I am using a shared server so I don't know the path for `include/geoip.inc` and I can't install any extension or plugin or to change the server configuration. I asked the provider but they suggested me to change path to /home/fuiba/php.ini because they ca not give me the path geoip.inc.

Comment: @Fuiba Like a specified in my post you can download it at this adress
https://github.com/maxmind/geoip-api-php/blob/master/src/geoip.inc

Then put in the `include/` folder or whatever you want just don't forget to put the right path then in the `include`

Comment: @ChrysUgwu `$gi = geoip_open('GeoIP.dat', GEOIP_MEMORY_CACHE);`